# PHP not recognizes a string, this show a number

Tags: php

I get any data from a mysql database and save on an array to use in a txt file:

```
$bpac[] = '03' . $bpa['cnes'] . date('Ym', strtotime($bpa['data'])) . $bpa['cns_medico'] . $bpa['co_ocupacao'] . date('Ymd', strtotime($bpa['data'])) . str_pad($folha, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . str_pad($linha, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . $bpa['co_procedimento'] . $bpa['cns_paciente'] . $bpa['sexo'] . $bpa['ibge'] . str_pad($bpa['co_cid'], 4, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT) . date('Y') - date('Y', strtotime($bpa['data_nascimento'])) . str_pad($bpa['quantidade'], 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . '01' . '             ' . 'EXT';
```

When I exe a `var_dump($bpac)` the return is `3.1231213202006E+7200000501             EXT`, instead `03123121320200612345620200519000101123456123489165167200000501             EXT`

I try to use `strval()` but it's not work.

Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure, but I saw `. str_pad($bpa['co_cid'], 4, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT) . date('Y') - date('Y', strtotime($bpa['data_nascimento'])` - in php `.` and `-` has same precedence so if you want to subtract year of `$bpa['data_nascimento']` from current year - you should use parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parenthesis to subtraction

```
. date('Y') - date('Y', strtotime($bpa['data_nascimento'])) .
```

like this

```
. (date('Y') - date('Y', strtotime($bpa['data_nascimento']))) .
```

Otherwise both strings will be converted to integers and because of too long as floats.